# Oracle PL/SQL - Dereference a string as a variable

Tags: oracle, pointers, plsql, dereference

Is it possible to dereference a string as a variable in PL/SQL?

I'm looking for something like this:

```sql
declare
    my_var     CONSTANT varchar2(50) := 'test';
    my_var_ref CONSTANT varchar2(50) := 'my_var';

begin
    -- This of course doesn't work, it's just to illustrate what I'm looking for:
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(&my_var_ref) -- Prints test
end;
```

---

Pass the name as a procedure parameter:

```sql
declare
    my_var     CONSTANT varchar2(50) := 'test';
    my_var_ref CONSTANT varchar2(50) := 'my_var';

begin
    my_func(&my_var_ref) -- Pass my_var instead of my_var_ref
end;
```

Comment: Not as such, no.  You might be able to do whatever you're hoping to accomplish with dynamic SQL (or dynamic PL/SQL) but that's a fairly large lift that would be very uncommon in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TL;DR] No, you cannot dereference a PL/SQL variable. However, an alternative option might be to use an associative array.

---

If you try to dereference it using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` then the PL/SQL block that is being dynamically evaluated has no knowledge of the context from the calling block so cannot get the value of the dereferenced variable.

For example:

```sql
DECLARE
  my_var      CONSTANT varchar2(50) := 'test';
  my_var_ref  CONSTANT varchar2(50) := 'my_var';
  value       VARCHAR2(50);
  plsql_block VARCHAR2(100) := 'BEGIN :value := ' || my_var_ref || '; END;';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( plsql_block );
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block USING IN OUT value;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( value );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SQLERRM );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> BEGIN :value := my_var; END;
> ORA-06550: line 1, column 17:
> PLS-00201: identifier 'MY_VAR' must be declared
> ```

It has got the correct variable name but the variable is not defined in the context within which the dynamic evaluation of the PL/SQL block is occurring so it doesn't work.

However, if you try to pass in the variable's value (rather than trying to dereference the variable) then this demonstrates that, apart from dereferencing, the rest of the code would work:

```sql
DECLARE
  my_var      CONSTANT varchar2(50) := 'test';
  my_var_ref  CONSTANT varchar2(50) := 'my_var';
  value       VARCHAR2(50);
  plsql_block VARCHAR2(100) := 'BEGIN :value := ''' || my_var || '''; END;';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( plsql_block );
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE plsql_block USING IN OUT value;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( value );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( SQLERRM );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> BEGIN :value := 'test'; END;
> test
> ```

---

However, you could use a PL/SQL associative array instead:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE MAP IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);
  my_var_ref CONSTANT VARCHAR2(50) := 'my_var';
  v_map MAP;
BEGIN
  v_map('my_var') := 'test';

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_map( my_var_ref) );
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> test
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6d52cbed67c480637f6dd59cea7ffd7a)*

Answer (score 0):

You can using packages.

```
create or replace package test_pkg as

   my_var1 varchar2(50);
   my_var2 varchar2(50);
   my_var3 varchar2(50);

   procedure set_val(p_var in varchar2,
                     p_val in varchar2);

   function get_val(p_var in varchar2)
     return varchar2;

end test_pkg;
/

create or replace package body test_pkg as

   procedure set_val(p_var in varchar2,
                     p_val in varchar2) is
   begin
      execute immediate 'begin
                            test_pkg.' || p_var || ' := :x;
                         end;'
        using p_val;
   end set_val;

   function get_val(p_var in varchar2)
     return varchar2 is
      v_value varchar2(50);
   begin
      execute immediate 'begin
                            :x := test_pkg.' || p_var || ';
                         end;'
        using out v_value;

      return v_value;
   end get_val;

end test_pkg;
/
```

Then

```
set serveroutput on
begin
   for i in 1 .. 3 loop
      test_pkg.set_val('my_var' || i, 'Test ' || i);
   end loop;

   for i in 1 .. 3 loop
      dbms_output.put_line('my_var' || i || ' = ' || test_pkg.get_val('my_var' || i));
   end loop;
end;
```

Output:

```
my_var1 = Test 1
my_var2 = Test 2
my_var3 = Test 3
```